# error when running git command inside Popen

Tags: python

Disclaimer: I'm extremely new at Python programming so I could be doing things very wrong here

All I want to do is run a git command from an open file. Here is the call that I am making

```
subprocess.Popen( 'git status', cwd = os.path.dirname( path ), shell = True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE )
```

and the error message I am receiving is this: /bin/sh: git: command not found

I have verified that it is pointing to the correct directory by doing a list of the files. Also if I open a file that is under subversion control and do an svn info command everything works perfectly. I'm at a total loss as to what I'm missing here.

Comment: Make sure `git` is in the `PATH` of the user the Python script is running as?

Comment: are you using svn or git ??? because you want to run in you subprocess `git status` and after you said that you did `svn info` !!! and i don't know if this may help but i think the error that you get mean that git is not installed in your system

Comment: as i specified its a different file under subversion control that the svn info command works on. i run both svn and git. and yes git is installed, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Amber said, do a 'which git' in a shell, it'll tell you where git is installed. Then call git with the full path, eq with /usr/bin/git :

```
subprocess.Popen( '/usr/bin/git status', cwd = os.path.dirname( path ), shell = True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE )
```