# Why does my post-receive hook hang while reading from a subprocess pipe?

Tags: python, git, subprocess, pipe

I'm running Gitolite over the Git repository and I have post-receive hook there. The script of this hook written in Python and fails after

```
proc = subprocess.Popen('git log', shell = True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out = proc.stdout.read()
```

It doesn't execute after these lines. If I run this script manually, it works perfect.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please improve your question by posting the relevant sections of your code, properly formatted. In addition, please post the actual error message you received, and what steps you've taken so far to investigate your programming issue.

Comment: Well, here's what I did. As mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844880/error-when-running-git-command-inside-popen I tried to specify full path to command and 'cwd' option of subprocess. I DO NOT receive any error messages, if I got them, I could investigate this issue by myself.

Comment: Have you gotten the output from a simpler command like just running 'git' to work?  Also, You might want to edit your question to include some of the information your placed in your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [subprocess documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html):

> Warning
>
> Use communicate() rather than .stdin.write, .stdout.read or
>   .stderr.read to avoid deadlocks due to any of the other OS pipe
>   buffers filling up and blocking the child process.

I'd avoid using `shell=True` if possible too (IMO it's only useful if you wanna use shell built-ins and it's platform/shell specific), and pass Popen command as a list, like `['git', 'log']`

Try something like:

```
>>> proc = subprocess.Popen(['git', 'log'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> proc.communicate()
('', 'fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git\n')
```

`communicate()[0]` is stdout, `communicate()[1]` is stderr.

Answer (score 0):

Your pipe is probably not returning. If that is the case, you can:

1. Run git with the `--no-pager` flag to prevent your PAGER or GIT_PAGER from hanging the process.
2. Limit your log output with the `-n` flag to keep piped output to a reasonable size. The [subprocess library](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) clearly says:

   > [T]he child process may block if it generates enough output to a pipe to fill up the OS pipe buffer.